# How do I add fields to the sidebar menu when creating/editing nodes?

Tags: 8, nodes

I would like to add to the sidebar menu on the create/edit node pages. How would I do this?

I would like to do this in order to make the content creating/editing a little cleaner and easier to understand for content editors.

See attached pic...

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I believe those form sections are treated differently by core. You would form alter and add them to that area. Here is an example of a module adding a custom section to the 'advanced' group: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/custom_pub/blob/8.x-1.x/custom_pub.module#L48

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of [Field Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) supports putting fields into the sidebar (at least for nodes).

Field Group version >= 3.0-rc2, containing [issue 2652642](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group/issues/2652642)

Answer (score 4):

How todo it custom in code such as in a hook_form_alter

```
$form['something'] = [
  "#title" => t('@title', ['@title' => 'My Title']),
  "#type" => "details",
  "#group" => "advanced",
  "#weight" => 50,
];

// Add fields to the group.
$form['something']['text'] = [
  "#title" => t('@title', ['@title' => 'test']),
  "#type" => "textfield",
  "#group" => "advanced",
  "#weight" => 50,
];
```